# Rotating Pixel Art with 2x Pixels in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a game which is using a pixel art style, upscaled so 1 pixel is equal to a 2x2 area onscreen. However, when I rotate a sprite in OpenGl it draws it using the screen pixels so it breaks the illusion of a low-res style game:

[image: Rotated sprite]

How can I rotate the sprite and draw it using the larger pixels? Right now sprites are drawn using a Sprite class with a method called Draw, and the code looks like this:

```
void Sprite::Draw(int x, int y, int w, int h, int tx = 0, int ty = 0, int tw = 1, int th = 1, int rotation = 0, int rx = 0, int ry = 0, int sr = 0, float r = 1, float g = 1, float b = 1) {
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTranslatef(x+(w/2), y+(h/2), 0);
glRotatef((float) sr, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-x-(w/2), -y-(h/2), 0);

glTranslatef(x+(w/2)+rx, y+(h/2)+ry, 0);
glRotatef((float) rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-(w/2)-rx, -(h/2)-ry, 0);
glColor3f(r, g, b);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

const float verts[] = {
    0, (float) h,
    (float) w, (float) h,
    0, 0,
    (float) w, 0
};

const float tVerts[] = {
    (float)tx/(float)width, ((float)ty+(float)th)/(float)height,
    ((float)tx+(float)tw)/(float)width, ((float)ty+(float)th)/(float)height,
    (float)tx/(float)width, (float)ty/(float)height,
    ((float)tx+(float)tw)/(float)width, (float)ty/(float)height
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tVerts);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glLoadIdentity();

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I guess I should mention I'm using SDL2 for window management.

Comment: So you want to rotate, then upscale? I think that might end up looking horrible. Traditional pixel art games don't do rotation, or they have hand-drawn sprites for a small set of orientations.

Comment: @Thomas It might, I don't know. I can hand-draw sprite rotations but this game has some orbital mechanics so it's important to be able to point the ship very precisely, meaning it would need probably 100 rotation sprites or so.

Comment: If the problem is that you are *seeing* the 'rotated pixels', then consider downscaling to "actual" pixels, rotating, then upscaling again.

Comment: @Jongware Scaling doesn't seem to work because OpenGL treats shapes as a matrix. Scaling the matrix just scales the size, not the texture as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render the whole scene at half the resolution, and then scale it up. To do this, you use a FBO (Frame Buffer Object) for your primary rendering, and then blit it to the default framebuffer.

Once, during setup, create your FBO and render target, and attach the render target to the FBO:

```
GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);

GLuint rbId = 0;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbId);
// Need to bind this once so object is created.
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

On every window resize, with the window resized to `width`/`height`, allocate the render target at half the window size. If your window is not resizable, you can combine this with the setup code:

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, width / 2, height / 2);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
```

On every redraw, render to the FBO, and blit the result to the default framebuffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glViewport(0, 0, width / 2, height / 2);

// draw content

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width / 2, height / 2,
                  0, 0, width, height,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The above assumes that `width` and `height` are even numbers. You may have to tweak it slightly if they can be odd.

Comment: Looks promising... but as soon as I generate a framebuffer it segfaults.

Comment: Most of this is GL 3.x level functionality. You may not have a context that supports this version.

Comment: How would I use OpenGL 3 stuff without getting rid of my old fashioned non-shader GL code?

Comment: Actually I'm linking GLEW now and it doesn't segfault. Progress!

Comment: You can use this with old features if your platform supports the compatibility profile. See https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute on how to configure your context with SDL, particularly the `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_*` attributes.